# How can I mathematically show the similarity between these 3 plots?

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation, correlation

I have 3 3D plots of field strength measured around an antenna.

[image]
[image]
[image]

I want to calculate the mathematical similarity between the points of the field patterns. How can I do this?

thanks

Comment: I have cropped your images slightly and added them to your post.  Do they look ok?

Comment: They look perfect, cheers

Answer (score 1):

There is more than one way to measure similarity.  Here are three.  They all start with $f(x,y)=|a(x,y)-b(x,y)|$, the function that measures the distance between plot $a$ and plot $b$, at every point.

Method 1: Take the maximum of $f(x,y)$ over the region.

Method 2: Take the integral of $f(x,y)$ over the region, i.e. the area underneath the surface.

Method 3: Take the integral of $f(x,y)^2$ over the region, and take the square root of the answer.

These are called [$L^p$ norms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space), specifically the $\infty$, $1$ and $2$ norms respectively.

Comment: By the way this is how I, a mathematician, would go about it.  A statistician I'm sure will have a completely different approach.

Comment: I'm actually an engineer - hence the absolutely clueless question. But the answer helps explain, cheers.